# Table for subject/course/section in sakai

Tags: sakai

I was trying to find a way to manually add data for the said tables but I couldn't find it. I also tried searching in google but I couldn't find a correct answer either.

Do you guys know what table do they represent? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't create *course* sites without having defined at least one academic term; if you haven't done so, Sakai leaves you in the cold, and the only way to fix it is to populate the database table in question, `CM_ACADEMIC_SESSION_T`, manually, by using an `INSERT` query.

The Sakai documentation doesn't explain how to do this, or whether it really suffices, but you can ask the `sakai-dev` mailing list or go by the answers to this question provided there in the past (e.g. [here](https://groups.google.com/a/apereo.org/forum/?nomobile=true#!msg/sakai-dev/9oOtQMwHaDU/e5ysrQ1oBAAJ) or [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.cms.sakai.user/6273)) and hope they still apply.  (This is typical for Sakai.)

An alternative is not to use *course* sites at all (I didn't trust them after discovering this) and use *project* sites instead.